# Красивые адреса OpenServer

Tags: yii

Установил Yii framework на OpenServer попытался настроить красивые url создал htaccess там прописал

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# Если запрос начинается с /admin, то заменяем на /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# Добавляем другой запрос /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# Если frontend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# Если backend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

по адресу advanced\frontend и advanced\backend тоже прописал htaccess

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

вовсех main всех конфигов поставил urlManager

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

и вот этот urlManager для main в common

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
```

но ничго не получается если нажать на пункты меню идет ошибка 404 по этому адресу http://advanced/frontend/web/site/index
в рецептах многие меняют настройки апач но у меня на openServere это не один проект и как понимаете это не вариант. Кто нибуть может подсказать как лучше постпить. Сразу оговорюсь в yii это мой первый учебный проект.

Comment: Отнюдь не ВСЯ. Надо перенаправлять запросы на точки входа приложений.

Comment: При наличии маршрутизации в yii вам не нужен rewrite в htaccess для реализации [ЧПУ](https://goo.gl/Xa64CG). Вся эта магия делается через [правила (rules) маршрутизатора](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/runtime-routing.md#url-rules-). `тоже прописал htaccess` Данный набор правил в htaccess организует единую точку доступа к ваше приложению и этого достаточно.

Comment: @Mik: Уже дополнял комментарий, когда вы меня поправили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня на нескольких проектах отлично себя зарекомендовал вот такой htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# Если запрос начинается с /admin, то заменяем на /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# Если запрос начинается с /api, то заменяем на /rest/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^api\/?(.*) /rest/web/$1

# Добавляем другой запрос /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|rest/web|admin|api)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# Если frontend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# Если api запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rest/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rest/web/index.php

# Если backend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

/rest/ - это папка с REST API. Если это Вам не нужно, можете удалить его из правил.

Answer (score 1):

все решилось вот этим .htacces

Options +FollowSymLinks

```
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on



# if request begins with /admin remove admin and ad /backend/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

# other requests add /frontend/web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

# if frontend request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# if backend request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Да, `Options +FollowSymLinks` необходима. Особенность Apache. Даёт право прохода по симлинкам.